# Hidden redirect IIS - web.config

Tags: iis, configuration, web-config, windows-server

I have an Windows Server hosted (IIS), in the root dir (head dir with FTP) I have a directory /www/ with an Angular SPA built, so an index.html inside.

I want to say to the server:

"Ehi, when people go to https://example.com you must to show www/index.html but with https://example.com on the URL" (**so not with https://example.com/www/**) is this possible??

And i have to say also:

"Ehi server! The routes are not real directory! This is an SPA!!" becouse the routing navigation is OK **but the refresh doesn't works**.

I think i have to write something on web.config file, but what?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I'm using:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" 
negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/www/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This works for refresh but for "hidden redirect"...

Comment: What is "the root dir"? No matter what you will need a web.config file as Angular asks you to https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Comment: root dir is the / dir with an FTP connection on the server https://example.com /

Comment: @LexLi this its ok for the SPA! Thanks! Do you know something about the "hidden redirect"? 
I have to put the web.config file in / and /www directories?

Comment: Why not set url to /www/index.html? You set to /www/ and rewrited url is http://domain/www/, how could it return index.html?

Comment: @BruceZhang index.html is implicit, I want to put the website inside a folder (www) and serve this on the https:/www.example.com URL as base-url. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know too much about angular, but if angular can ignore /www in url, this may possible.

Comment: No, I was thinking was something on the server config

Comment: You can use failed request tracing to view request processing in IIS. The first is url rewriting. If you use current rewrite rule, the request is http://example.com, after rewriting, it is http://exampl.com/www/, so I suggest you modify it to /www/index.html, After rewriting it is http://example.com/www/index.html. Not sure what you mean index.html is implicit. But this allows IIS to find index.html in www folder. You need to set up angular's route to prevent http://example.com/www/index.html from being processed by angular route, which will think that www corresponds to a route name.